# How to populate a Vuetify Select using data from axios

Tags: vue.js, html-select, axios, vuetify.js

I need to populate a Vuetify select, but there is a problem with it, my Get method returns data, but the vuetify select only show something like this:
[image]

The text shows valid data:

```
[ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 2 } ]
```

And to populate the Select i follow the documentatioin adding `:items="entidades" and :item-text="entidades.id" and :item-value="entidades.id"`

```
<v-select :items="entidades" :item-text="entidades.id" :item-value="entidades.id" single-line auto prepend-icon="group_work" label="Seleccionar Grupo"></v-select>
```

This is my code form script

```
`data() {
return(){
entidades: [{
          id: ''  
        }],
}
}`
```

I already tried to put 0, but it's the same result.

My axios.get method.

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:58209/api/GetEntidades', {
      headers:{
       "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
  })
    .then(response => { 
      console.log(response)
      this.entidades = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
        });
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`item-text` and `item-value` are the ***name*** of the properties each item will display and use as value, respectively. So use `item-text="id" item-value="id"`:

```
<v-select :items="entidades" item-text="id" item-value="id" single-line auto prepend-icon="group_work" label="Seleccionar Grupo"></v-select>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      entidades: [ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 2 } ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.10/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.10/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-select :items="entidades" item-text="id" item-value="id" single-line auto prepend-icon="group_work" label="Seleccionar Grupo"></v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, is the same result but with warning:

Property or method "id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: I don´t know but i copied your <v-select > and now it´s working, I suppose it's because I used :item-text and you use item-text whithout :

Comment: Yes, without `:`. When you use `:item-text="someValue"` it will look for the `someValue` variable in the current scope. In your case, you probably used `:item-text="id"` and likely got an error, because there shouldn't be an `id` variable in the current scope (`id` is a property of each `entidade`, not a variable of its own).